# How do I omit the port for well-known protocols in a Helm template procedure?

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

I need to define a url in my Helm template such that the colon and port are omitted if the (protocol, port) are either (`http`, 80) or (`https`, 443).

Correct:

- http://myservice:8080
- https://myservice:8443
- http://myservice
- https://myservice

Incorrect:

- http://myservice:80
- https://myservice:443

How would I go about doing this in a procedure definition in my `_helpers.tpl`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Including the port number isn't usually harmful (`https://stackoverflow.com:443` is valid); do you need to omit it?  Or, if the URLs' destination is a cluster-internal Service, can you set the Service to listen on the normal HTTP ports?

Comment: This is required for matching against an an audience claim on a token.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do this in `_helpers.tpl`:

```
{{/*
Optionally append the port to a url if non well-known.
*/}}
{{- define "non-well-known-port" -}}
{{- if or (and (eq .protocol "http") (eq (.port | int) 80)) (and (eq .protocol "https") (eq (.port | int) 443)) }}
{{- printf "" }}
{{- else }}
{{- printf ":%d" (.port | int) }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And to call this, I build a `dict` with the `port` and `protocol` values so I can pass them in:

```
...
{{- $portData := dict "protocol" ($.Values.myservice.public.protocol) "port" ($.Values.myservice.public.port) }}
{{- printf "%s://%s%s" ($.Values.myservice.public.protocol) (include ".Values.myservice.hostname") (include "non-well-known-port" $portData) }}
...
```

This solution omits the `:80` if the protocol is `http`, and omits the `:443` if the protocol is `https`.  For any other port and protocol value, a colon and the port number are printed.